# How to pass Django Template Tags to an html file that is not in the URLPatterns?

Tags: html, django

I am seriously new to Django, so it is much appreciated if you are reading my question!
I have a CRM Project I am working on in Django,and I have a Navigation Bar that loads from the side, written in a separate html file (navBar.html) and added to main.html (a file that contains all common front end items in every page of the website) using {% include 'crm/navBar.html' %}.
[Navigation Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDhjY.png)

There is an "Add+" button that is supposed to act as a drop down menu. The options of such drop down menu should come from a model called "Sale_Steps" using template tags.

**The Problem is**:
I am struggling to import Sales_Steps into navBar.html, here is the code in a nutshell:

***in views.py***

```
def NavBar(request):
Sale_steps = Sales_Step.objects.all()
context = {'sale_step':Sale_steps}
return render(request, 'crm/navBar.html',context)
```

***in urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', crm_views.home_page),
path('home/',crm_views.home_page),
path('sales/', crm_views.sales_page),
path('all_queries/',crm_views.all_queries_page),
path('Queries/',crm_views.all_queries_page),
path('checkQuery/',crm_views.check_query_page),
path('Customers/',crm_views.all_customers_page),
path('checkCustomer/',crm_views.check_customer_page),


path('blank/',crm_views.blank_page),
```

]

***in navBar.html***

```
{% for s in sale_step %}
       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{s.Name}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

navbar.html:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="text-align:left;">
        <span onclick="showme('ADD')"  class="dropdown-btn"><i class="fa fa-tachometer-alt" style="float:left;width:8%;"></i>&emsp;DADD+   <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></span>
            <div id="ADD" class="dropdown-container" style="display:none;"></div>

</div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get("{% url 'stack:navBar' %}", function(data, status){
            list = JSON.stringify(data);
            context = JSON.parse(list);
            // node
            var node;
            // textnode
            var href;
            // style
            var style;
            // TX
            alert(context['sale_step']);
            while (context['sale_step']) {
                node = document.createElement("a");// Create a <a> node

                textnode = document.createTextNode("- "+ context['sale_step']);  // Create a text node

                node.appendChild(textnode);

                href = document.createAttribute("href");       // Create a "class" attribute

                href.value = "www.google.com"; // Set the value of the class attribute

                node.setAttributeNode(href);

                style = document.createAttribute("style");

                style.value = "font-size:16px;";

                node.setAttributeNode(style);

                document.getElementById("ADD").appendChild(node);
                i++;
                }
     });
});


function showme(ID) {
    var x = document.getElementById(ID);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
       } else {
     x.style.display = "none";
  }
  }
</script>
```

views.py

```
def navBar(request):
    context = {}
    sale = Ricavi.objects.values_list('quantita', flat=True)
    for x in sale:
        context['sale_step'] = x
    print(context)
    return JsonResponse(context)
```

main.html:

```
{% include 'TOPFOLDERNAME/navbar.html' %}
```

Comment: thank you for your approach, unfortunately although I followed it, it did not solve my problem, I do appreciate your trial anyway! Thank you so much!

Comment: In other words, the variable s is not filling the dropdown menu selector when I click on Add+

Comment: I tested it before sending

Comment: Ok, maybe I did a mistake somewhere:

urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('', crm_views.home_page),
    path('home/',crm_views.home_page),
    path('sales/', crm_views.sales_page),
    path('all_queries/',crm_views.all_queries_page),
    path('Queries/',crm_views.all_queries_page),
    path('checkQuery/',crm_views.check_query_page),
    path('Customers/',crm_views.all_customers_page),
    path('checkCustomer/',crm_views.check_customer_page),

    #New One
    path('NavBar',crm_views.NavBar,name='NavBar'),


    path('blank/',crm_views.blank_page),
]

(to be continued)

Comment: def NavBar(request):
    Sale_steps = Sales_Step.objects.values_list('Name',flat=True)
    context = {'sale_step':Sale_steps}
    return render(request, 'crm/navBar.html',context)

Comment: {% for s in sale_step %}
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">{{s}}</a>
            {% endfor %}

Comment: does it have to do with the fact that navBar is included, into main.html ?

Comment: This is another issue which also have many solutions.

Comment: In this case your view must return a json response with data and in you navbar.html you need J.script (Get function) to get data and create a dynamic nav bar

Comment: And finaly in main.html you insert {% include 'You_to_folder'/navbar.html' %}

Comment: AND DONE!  ANSWER UPDATED! @HGEIM

Comment: This is what we call dynamic navigation Bar or menu